# AngularJS: don't remove data until resource loads

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-resource

I'm completely new to `$resource` so I'm not sure how to use it.

(this is not the real code but it is similar)

service:

```
.factory('User', function ($resource) {
            return $resource(apiPath + 'user/:id', {}, {
                query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
            })
        })
```

controller:

```
$scope.showUser = function(userID){
    $scope.user = User.get({id:userID});
}
```

view:

```
<button ng-click="showUser(user.id+1)">Show user</button>

<h1>{{user.name}}</h1>
```

It works great, but every time I press the button, the user's name disappears and then appears when the data is returned - `$scope.user` becomes empty until the next user is loaded. I don't want that, I want the old user to remain until the next user is loaded. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a callback function, which will be executed when the resource has been fetched.

```
 // Not assigning the return value here on the scope ...

 User.get({ id: userID}, function(user) {

      // ... but rather here when the call has completed.

      $scope.user = user;

 });
```

See the [$resource documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) for more info.